# npm errror while installing package in new machine

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I Want to install package from ShrinkWrap.json file , I am trying to install package in new machine but command `npm install` is throwing 
error

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/build/Source/Web/node_modules/.staging/whet.extend-0ac707ec/package.json

**Expected Behavior :**
I want the package to be installed correctly

**What I tried so far :**
Removed node_modules folder and deleted package-lock.json file and `npm cache clean --force` as well

Details
**Node version** : 10.17.0

Note : I want to install the package from shrinkwrap.json file only

Comment: Try updating your `npm` and then try using `npm install` and see if it works.

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using npm shrinkwrap, you need the `package.json` file in addition to the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file. The error says it can't find the `package.json` file.

Comment: I have package.json file as well

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are in the correct folder? To be honest, that file path does look a bit odd.